# In Pdf.js Library , which file calls the read_pdf function to fetch the data of pdf from server to client end?

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, pdf.js

In Pdf.js Library , which file calls the read_pdf function 
 to fetch the data of pdf from server to client end ?

Comment: there is no read_pdf function in https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js library

Comment: @async5 ya but from where does the library calls to fetch the data of pdf from server to client ?

Answer (score 0):

> > there is no read_pdf function in http://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js library
>
> ya but from where does the library calls to fetch the data of pdf from server to client

Are you just fishing for an answer how PDF.js loads data? If it is, then PDF.js uses XHR in the worker code (pdf.worker.js) to fetch binary PDF data as arraybuffer. It might use several HTTP (range) requests the get this data if server (script) signals that it can support range requests.

Comment: are you talking about src/core/worker.js or web/worker.js because there are two files named worker.js , i could not find any pdf.worker.js  in any folder.

Comment: pdf.worker.js is collection of src/core/ and src/shared/ files